# bcp export data to txt having arabic filename

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode, arabic, xp-cmdshell

I'm trying to export data to txt file having arabic filename using **xp_cmdshell**

It is working fine. the problem is when I **tried to name the file in arabic** i got this **error** message

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Find below the query:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell N'bcp "SELECT FirstName,LastName,Salary FROM MyDB.dbo.Employee" queryout "\\myserver\FDS\سسيسي.txt" -SFDSLAP\SQLR2 -UmyUser -PmyPass -T -w -t "'
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens with me when the file is opened by another program and sometimes when the path specified will create a new directory.